# How can one attach two network interfaces to a single pod in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, kubernetes-pod

I want two different ethernet interfaces on my application pod. Is there any possible way to achieve this in kubernetes?

Comment: Pods don't have Ethernet interfaces, computers do. Do you mean, "IP addresses"?

Comment: no i mean network interfaces. like in docker whne we add the container to more than one network, it has that number of network interfaces, the similar kind!

Comment: Have you found any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As per Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/#networking) each pod have unique IP address.

> Each Pod is assigned a unique IP address. Every container in a Pod
>   shares the network namespace, including the IP address and network
>   ports. Containers inside a Pod can communicate with one another using
>   localhost. When containers in a Pod communicate with entities outside
>   the Pod, they must coordinate how they use the shared network
>   resources (such as ports).

However, during searching information about multiple `pod` interfaces I found that [Multus](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/#multus-a-multi-network-plugin) should be able to do what you need.

> Multus is a Multi CNI plugin to support the Multi Networking feature
>   in Kubernetes using CRD based network objects in Kubernetes.

There is more information about this plugin in [Github](https://github.com/intel/multus-cni).

> Multus CNI is a container network interface (CNI) plugin for
>   Kubernetes that enables attaching multiple network interfaces to pods.

You can also find some [multus examples](https://github.com/intel/multus-cni/tree/master/examples) for macvlan or flannel.

Hope it will help.

Comment: is there any other way to achieve it without any external plug-ins?